# how to pass variable jquery a tag onclick function

Tags: jquery

i was use this code jquery onclick function on a tag "citychoose"

```
<a href="#" onclick="citychoose('+ item +')" class="tags1">'+ item +'</a>
```

citychoose data can't worked... how to call the function

how to solve this function

```
function citychoose(data) {
   alert(data);
}
```

full code of my function

```
function panelHtml(data) {
    var html = '<div class="panel panel-primary">';
             html += '<div class="panel-heading">Search Your State</div>';
                 html += '<div class="panel-body">';
                    $.each(data, function(index , item){
                        /*html += "<a href='#' onclick='citychoose('"+ item +"')' class='tags1' id='hand'>"+ item +"</a>";*/
                        html += '<a href="#" onclick="citychoose('+ item +')" class="tags1">'+ item +'</a>';
                    });
                  html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
    return html;
}

function citychoose(data) {
   alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are passing value is not right, try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="citychoose(this.innerHTML);" class="tags1">'+ item +'</a>
```

Check the demo i provided below

```js
function citychoose(data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="citychoose(this.innerHTML);" class="tags1">item</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation for dynamically added elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.tags1', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    citychoose($(this).text());
});
```

in your each method remove the onclick method

```
$.each(data, function(index , item){
     html += '<a href="#" class="tags1">'+ item +'</a>';
});

function citychoose(data) {
   alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,remove onclick

```
 $(function(){
        $(".tags1").click(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("item"));
        });
    });
```